# String Manipulation in Numba Cuda: Clip first k characters from a string array, k comes from another array

Tags: python, cuda, nvidia, numba, jit

We have two arrays `arr1` (which has string elements) and `arr2` (which has integers).
I want to clip first `arr2[i]` characters from `arr[i]`. These arrays are very large and so I want to implement this in `Numba` cuda. Pythonic implementation is as follows:

```
arr1 = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz']
arr2 = [1,2,3]

def python_clipper(arr1,arr2):
    for i in range(len(arr1)):
        arr1[i] = arr1[i][arr2[i]:]
    return arr1

print(python_clipper(arr1,arr2)) # ['bc', 'f', '']
```

The above implementation works fine. But when I create a `cuda` function out of this python function like so:

```
@cuda.jit()
def cuda_clipper(arr1,arr2):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    arr1[i] = arr1[i][arr2[i]:]

blockspergrid, threadsperblock = len(arr1),1
cuda_clipper[blockspergrid, threadsperblock](arr1,arr2) # ['bc', 'f', '']
print(arr1)
```

I get the following error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function _empty_string at 0x7f0456884d30>) found for signature:
 
 >>> _empty_string(int64, int64, bool)
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'register_jitable.<locals>.wrap.<locals>.ov_wrap': File: numba/core/extending.py: Line 159.
        With argument(s): '(int64, int64, bool)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         NumbaRuntimeError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
       NRT required but not enabled
       During: lowering "s = call $10load_global.3(kind, char_width, length, is_ascii, func=$10load_global.3, args=[Var(kind, unicode.py:276), Var(char_width, unicode.py:276), Var(length, unicode.py:276), Var(is_ascii, unicode.py:276)], kws=(), vararg=None, varkwarg=None, target=None)" at /mnt/local-raid10/workspace/user/anaconda3/envs/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cpython/unicode.py (277)
  raised from /mnt/local-raid10/workspace/user/anaconda3/envs/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/core/runtime/context.py:19

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function _empty_string at 0x7f0456884d30>)
During: typing of call at /mnt/local-raid10/workspace/user/anaconda3/envs/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cpython/unicode.py (1700)


File "../../anaconda3/envs/condaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numba/cpython/unicode.py", line 1700:
            def getitem_slice(s, idx):
                <source elided>
                    # It's heterogeneous in kind OR stride != 1
                    ret = _empty_string(kind, span, is_ascii)
                    ^

During: typing of intrinsic-call at /mnt/local-raid10/workspace/user/trim/trim_new_implementation/string_numba.py (143)

File "string_numba.py", line 143:
def cuda_clipper(arr1,arr2):
    <source elided>
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    arr1[i] = arr1[i][arr2[i]:]
    ^
```

I am under the impression that slicing the string is the problem as a similar implementation works fine with an array. I have tried to make the `arr1` into an array of array, but that preprocess itself takes some time rendering `cuda` useless to improve the performance. How can I directly work with `str` within `numba` rather than thinking of circumventing the problem.

Comment: You can’t do this. There is no list creation support and no string support in Numba on CUDA devices.

Comment: In fact, Numba strings are not even well supported on CPU yet. Only a part of the string functions are supported and nearly all string operations are insanely slow (generally much slower than CPython).

Answer (score 4):

> We have two arrays `arr1` (which has string elements) and `arr2` (which has integers)

You don't have arrays. You have lists. As you can see from the [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cuda/cudapysupported.html#built-in-types), there is no python string or list support on the GPU.

Therefore what you are trying to do is currently not supported in Numba CUDA.